# Recursive piping in Unix again Part 2

Tags: c, shell, recursion, pipe, file-descriptor

I know this topic has been posted about quite a bit, but I'm looking to take it in a different direction. I would like to write a program that has shell piping functionality, i.e. cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 piping and redirects. I have read pages like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307013/recursive-piping-in-unix-again), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332970/pipe-with-fork-with-recursion-file-descriptors-handling), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389033/implementation-of-multiple-pipes-in-c) for reference. And these solutions work great for "horizontal pipelining" but I would like to implement it "vertically". For my shell to be vertical, each 'command' process must have a different parent (the previous command). So, each command to be executed is spawned from the previous. The issue I have been having is that when I recurse in the child (rather than the parent like the examples), the program executes fine but then hangs and I must hit enter to reprompt my shell. I'm curious why this is different and how to fix this.

```
static void exec_pipeline(size_t pos, int in_fd) {
    // Invalid Pipe has issues
    if (newargv[pipe_commands[pos+1]] == NULL)
        report_error_and_exit("Invalid pipe");
/* last command, pipe_command conatins indices of commands to execute */
    if (pipe_commands[pos + 1] == 0) { 
        redirect(in_fd, STDIN_FILENO); /* read from in_fd, write to STDOUT */
        execvp(newargv[pipe_commands[pos]], newargv + pipe_commands[pos]);
        report_error_and_exit("execvp last command");
    }
    else { /* $ <in_fd cmds[pos] >fd[1] | <fd[0] cmds[pos+1] ... */
        int fd[2]; /* output pipe */
        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
            report_error_and_exit("pipe");
        switch(fork()) {
            case -1:
                report_error_and_exit("fork");
            case 0: /* parent: execute the rest of the commands */
                CHK(close(fd[1])); /* unused */
                CHK(close(in_fd)); /* unused */
                exec_pipeline(pos + 1, fd[0]); /* execute the rest */
            default: /* child: execute current command `cmds[pos]` */
                child = 1;
                CHK(close(fd[0])); /* unused */
                redirect(in_fd, STDIN_FILENO);  /* read from in_fd */
                redirect(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO); /* write to fd[1] */
                execvp(newargv[pipe_commands[pos]], newargv + pipe_commands[pos]);
                report_error_and_exit("execvp");

        }
    }
}
void report_error_and_exit(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    (child ? _exit : exit)(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* move oldfd to newfd */
void redirect(int oldfd, int newfd) {
    if (oldfd != newfd) {
        if (dup2(oldfd, newfd) != -1)
            CHK(close(oldfd));
        else
            report_error_and_exit("dup2");
    }
}
```

CHK is a lot like assert, defined in a file called CHK.h, and looks like this if you're curious:

```
  do {if((x) == -1)\
   {fprintf(stderr,"In file %s, on line %d:\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
    fprintf(stderr,"errno = %d\n",errno);\
    perror("Exiting because");\
    exit(1);\
   }\
 } while(0)
```

Comment: Update: the issue is how I am waiting for processes to finish up, I'm currently investigating a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! So the problem was that with the vertical implementation, the last command to execute was 'cmd3' which it should have been 'cmd1'. Not a perfect solution but works. Basically just flipped the direction of building the pipe. This solution still has some file descriptor issues with passed in input though.

```
static void exec_pipe(size_t pos, int in_fd) {
    // Invalid Pipe has issues
    if (newargv[pipe_commands[pos+1]] == NULL) {
        report_error_and_exit("Invalid pipe");
    }
    if (pipe_commands[pos + 1] == 0) { /* last command */
        redirect(in_fd, STDOUT_FILENO); /* read from in_fd, write to STDOUT */
        execvp(newargv[pipe_commands[PIPE_FLAG-pos]], newargv + pipe_commands[PIPE_FLAG-pos]);
        report_error_and_exit("execvp last command");
    } else { /* $ <in_fd cmds[pos] >fd[1] | <fd[0] cmds[pos+1] ... */
        int fd[2]; /* output pipe */
        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
            report_error_and_exit("pipe");
        switch(fork()) {
            case -1:
                report_error_and_exit("fork");
            case 0: /* child: execute the rest of the commands */
                CHK(close(fd[0])); /* unused */
                CHK(close(in_fd)); /* unused */
                exec_pipe(pos + 1, fd[1]); /* execute the rest */
            default: /* parent: execute current command `cmds[pos]` */
                child = 1;
                CHK(close(fd[1])); /* unused */
                redirect(in_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);  /* read from in_fd */
                redirect(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO); /* write to fd[0] */
                execvp(newargv[pipe_commands[PIPE_FLAG-pos]], newargv + pipe_commands[PIPE_FLAG-pos]);
                report_error_and_exit("execvp");
        }
    }
}

void pipeHelper() {
    pid_t dad;
    (void) fflush(stdin);
    (void) fflush(stdout);

    // Check for successful fork
    if ((dad = fork()) < 0)
        report_error_and_exit("fork");
    else if (dad == 0) {
        // Catch input redirect
        // Copy input file description to standard in descriptor then close
        if (IN_FLAG == 1)
            redirect(input_file_description, STDIN_FILENO);
        // Catch output redirect
        // Copy output file description to standard out descriptor then close
        if (OUT_FLAG == 1)
            redirect(output_file_description, STDOUT_FILENO);
        // Catch input redirect
        if (HEREIS_FLAG > 0 && BAIL_FLAG == 0)
            redirect(hereis_file_description, STDIN_FILENO);
        // Redirect to /dev/null
        if (AMP_FLAG != 0 && IN_FLAG == 0)
            redirect(devnull_file_description, STDIN_FILENO);
        exec_pipe(0, STDIN_FILENO);
        //exec_pipeline(0, STDIN_FILENO);
    } else {
        if (AMP_FLAG != 0) {
            (void) printf("%s [%d]\n", newargv[0], dad);
            AMP_FLAG = 0;
        } else {
            for (;;) {
                pid_t pid;
                pid = wait(NULL);
                if (pid == dad)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```